# allennlp.common.JsonDict, TypeError: FileLock.acquire: `poll_intervall` is not present

Tags: python, allennlp

would you please tell me why when i use the following script:

```
from allennlp.common import JsonDict
```

i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-58adc5745662> in <module>()
----> 1 from allennlp.common import JsonDict

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/overrides/signature.py in ensure_all_kwargs_defined_in_sub(super_sig, sub_sig, super_type_hints, sub_type_hints, check_first_parameter, method_name)
    134             name, True, sub_has_var_kwargs, sub_sig, super_param
    135         ):
--> 136             raise TypeError(f"{method_name}: `{name}` is not present.")
    137         elif name in sub_sig.parameters and super_param.kind != Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD:
    138             sub_index = list(sub_sig.parameters.keys()).index(name)

TypeError: FileLock.acquire: `poll_intervall` is not present.
```

Comment: Can you specify the `allennlp` version?

Comment: Good question. I changed the version and the problem solved. Thanks.